# How can I make the items in a list replicate the properties they hold i.e. font name Arial to be shown in the list as font Arial?

Tags: google-apps-script, fonts

I am using Google Apps Script and need to show a list of fonts the user can choose from. I want the list to show the list of fonts in their respective font family.

Here is the list of fonts:

```
 let fonts = [
        {id:1, name:"Tahoma"}, 
        {id:2, name:"Merriweather"}, 
        {id:3, name:"Pacifico"}
      ]
```

Here is the code for populating the list:

```
for (let i=0; i<fonts.length; i++) {
             $('#selFonts').append(`<option style="font-family:${fonts[i].name}">${fonts[i].name}</option>`);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinlistvalues,-showdropdown)

```
function onOpen(e) {
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Tahoma', 'Merriweather', 'Pacifico'], true).build();
    cell.setDataValidation(rule);
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I am actually using the Google Apps Script editor for Google Docs not Sheets so cannot grab the element by its cell.